# Why won't my child component render props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set up a React Frontend with a Node backend for an app I am trying to make. I have successfully created a server which is hosting my data, which I can then access and receive into my React Frontend. I am able to console.log the data I want and successfully saved it to the state (I think?). My issue is that I can't seem to actually pass the information contained in State into the child component.

Units.js

```
import UnitsCard from "./InfoCardUnits";
import React, { Component } from "react";
const axios = require("axios");

class Units extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      units: []
    };
  }

  fetchData() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/allData/units")
      .then(response => {
        // handle success
        // console.log("Success");
        this.setState({ units: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    // this console.log will show the data I want to send as props into my child component.
    console.log(this.state.units[0]);
    return <UnitsCard props={this.state.units[0]} />;
  }
}

export default Units;
```

InfoUnitCard.js

```
import "../index.css";

function UnitsCard(props) {
  // this console.log will show the "props" information that I want to use in my unit card. But the information itself won't actually show in the browser.
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <h2>{props.category}</h2>
      <h2>{props.inf_melee}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UnitsCard;
```

When I console.log the state in either of the components it successfully shows the information I am trying to send. But I can't actually get that information to render. Any help or insights would be much appreciated.

EDIT: This has been resolved, thanks very much to everyone who chipped in an answer.

Comment: Note that `this.state.units[0]` is `undefined` until the data is fetched. You want to handle that case somehow.

Comment: Yea, I get an undefined console.log before I get a console.log with the correct info in it. Do you have any recommendations on how to fix it or what best practice is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid passing props in via the `props` keyword. Instead, consider making the following changes to your code:

```
render() {

    // Get unit or empty object (makes code more readable in next step)
    const unit = this.state.units[0] || {};

    // Pass each piece of unit data in as a separate prop
    return <UnitsCard 
      name={unit.name} 
      category={unit.category} 
      inf_melee={unit.inf_melee} />;
 }
```

Alternatively, you could use the "spread" syntax available with ES6 to make this a little more concise:

```
render() {

    // Get unit or empty object (makes code more readable in next step)
    const unit = this.state.units[0] || {};

    // Use spread operator to simplify passing of props to UnitsCard
    return <UnitsCard {...unit} />;
 }
```

Comment: Or `<UnitsCard {...props} />`

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the feedback! I just updated the answer to include your suggestion - thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Every thing you pass in the child component will be available in props object in the child component. In your case you are passing a 'props' to props object. This should be available as this.props.props.keyname. try changing your child component as follow.

```
function UnitsCard(props) {
  // this console.log will show the "props" information that I want to use in my unit card. But the information itself won't actually show in the browser.
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{props.props.name}</h2>
      <h2>{props.props.category}</h2>
      <h2>{props.props.inf_melee}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You named your props `props`, so you can access to it with below code:

```
console.log(props.props);
```

you can pass like with a different name:

```
<UnitsCard child={this.state.units[0]} />
```

Then access to props with `props.child`, so your code will change to:

```
<h2>{props.child.name}</h2>
```